# Does media9 have a "demo" mode?

Tags: compiling, media9

Is there a way to temporarily prevent media9 from including videos? I was thinking about something similar to the "demo" option that can be given to the graphicx package. I have some largeish videos, and it slows down compilation time.

Thanks in advance,

Keith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use the `draft` option when loading the `media9` package. In draft mode, `media9` does not embed video, but instead only displays the placeholder graphic. Using `demo` for `graphicx` in conjunction with this would change even the placeholder graphic to a plain box.

Not only is the compilation time faster, but the PDF filesize is also greatly reduced.

**Notes for the example**

The code for the video embedding is taken directly from the [`media9` package manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/media9). The required media files are `cube.mp4` and `cubeposter.png`, both available from the [`media9` distribution](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/files/).

Place the media files in the same directory as your document (sample code below) and compile with `pdflatex`. Adobe Reader and a suitable Flash Player/Plugin for your operating system are required for the video to be viewable when embedded.

The placeholder image (`cubeposter.png`) will be shown only. Removing `draft` option adds the video back in.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[draft]{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \includemedia[
    addresource=cube.mp4,
    flashvars={
      source=cube.mp4
      &autoPlay=true % start playing on activation
      &loop=true
    }
  ]{\includegraphics[height=0.2\linewidth]{cubeposter}}{VPlayer9.swf}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]